# Georeferencing an NDVI (JPEG) image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am struggling to georeference a NDVI image. 
The image is a JPEG, how would I go about this?
I am using QGIS

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I think you might need to provide a bit more information. What software you are using, what you have tried, possibly a screen shot, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am using QGIS on apple mac, it is the only software that I have tried using.

Comment: And what have you tried in QGis?

Comment: Ive installed the open layer plugin but it only gives me options to use Google and Bing maps or streets. I have the image saved as a JPEG

Comment: do you know where the JPG is a picture of?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on georeferencing that may come in handy to you: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html . If you are stuck at a particular point, try to edit your question with details on where you are stuck.